# Subspace in $I-T$ for bounded linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be a bounded linear map.Show that the range of $I - T$ contains the subspace
$$Y_T = \{x \in X: \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^2\|T^nx\| < \infty \}$$

I have really no good idea how to solve this, 
any hints would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in Y_T$then we have some $c>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $ n^2\Vert T^n x\Vert<C$ for all $n>N$. This guarantees that the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \Vert T^n x\Vert
$$
converges. Since $X$ is Banach this implies that the series 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n x
$$
converges. Denote its sum by $y$, then
$$
Ty=
T\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty T^n x\right)=
T\left(\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N T^n x\right)=
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}T\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^N T^n x\right)=
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N T^{n+1} x=\\
\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N+1} T^n x=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} T^n x=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n x - x=y-x
$$
Hence
$$
x=y-Ty=(I-T)y\in \mathrm{Im}(I-T)
$$
The rest is clear.

Comment: How do we know that it is well definied for any k?
When you check the straightforward part what happens to the $-T^\infty$ part in the telescopic sum?

Comment: Ok I can write more detaled proof.

Comment: that would be great!